# read one line with integers c++

Tags: c++, file, input, int

i am making an algorithm and i need to read a whole line full of integers in c++
my input file is :

//////

5

6 3 4 2 5

//////

i want to read the second line and take the integers one by one
I don't want to take the integers to a variable because i have a memory limit(64 mb of ram)
i want to take the integers directly from the file
is there any way to do it in c++(not c)

i have tried this

```
fstream file;
file.open("file.txt");
int a;
file >> a;
```

But with this i can make it only read the "5" and if i use something like "getline();" i can't get each integer as i want
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to store these numbers, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: The Apollo 11 guidance computer had 2K of RAM.  (OK, it also had 32K of read only memory). You can do *a lot* with 64MB!

Comment: Use `while (file >> a) ...do something with a...;` to process each successive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to save each integer in its own variable, simply re-use the same one

```
fstream file("file.txt");
int a;
while (file >> a) {
   // Do your stuff with "a"
}
```

---

To skip the first number (as per the question below), one easy way is to read and discard the integer once:

```
fstream file("file.txt");
int a;
file >> a; // Do nothing with a → Discard the first value
while (file >> a) {
   // Do your stuff with "a"
}
```

Comment: and how to start reading from the second line of the file(because i dont want to read the "5" and i cant do something like if(a==5) because the "5" is a number tht i gave for example abnd i dont know what numbers the user will use